# How to properly calculate minimum zoom factor for UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIScrollView` that contains a single `UIImageView`. I am trying to set the minimum scroll factory so that when the view is fully zoomed out, the entire picture can be seen and stretches across the entire screen.

Currently my code seems to set the minimum too low. The entire picture can be seen, but there is a lot of extra space on the right side of the picture. There is so much extra space when the view appears that the image can be completely moved out of view. Once another zoom is performed, a lot of the extra space goes away, but the image can still be zoomed too small.

Here is the code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    imageView.image = image!
    imageView.frame.size = image!.size
    scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size

    let scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame
    let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
    let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
    let minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0
    scrollView.zoomToRect(imageView.frame, animated: false)
}
```

Edit: The sizes seem to be changing before and after zoom.

Before zoom:

```
Scroll view frame: (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 600.0)
Scroll view content size: (1500.0, 1001.0)
Image view frame: (0.0, 0.0, 1500.0, 1001.0)
```

After zoom:

```
Scroll view frame: (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 600.0)
Scroll view content size: (600.0, 400.4)
Image view frame: (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 400.4)
```

Comment: Your code looks pretty solid. What are the values for scrollView.frame and scrollView.contentSize anyway?

Comment: `scrollView.frame = (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 600.0)` and `scrollView.contentSize = (600.0, 400.4)`

Comment: Instead of calculating based off contentSize, try using imageView.frame.size. Also, if you hardcode zoom to .67, do you still see the white screen?

Comment: 0.67 does seem like the correct constant, but there is still a lot of empty space in the content view until a zoom takes places. Once a zoom happens, the content size seems to fit tightly to the image view.

Comment: It seems like `zoomToRect` is changing the image frame size which is why there is a bunch of extra space and the image is too small.

Answer (score 1):

This issue what that the autolayout constraints have not been calculated in `viewWillAppear`. To fix this, I moved the logic to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the minimum zoom factor, ensuring there is no extra space around the edges, you should use `max` rather than `min`.

```
let scaleWidth = scrollView.frame.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
let scaleHeight = scrollView.frame.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
let minScale = max(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
```